# Iterate Two Lists and Combine Same Values in New Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, asp.net-web-api

I've got two lists of data from two different databases that both share a common column. I want iterate through both lists and if the common value in ListA is found while iterating through ListB I want to add two new columns to that same row on ListA. Once it has done that for each row, I will just display the result of the primary list or add it to a new list if that is a better way of doing it...

```
//Create a list to store blink details data in from the AMI...
List<getBlinksModel> blinkList = new List<getBlinksModel>();

//Create a list for the as400 data...
List<getBlinksModel> as400GPSList = new List<getBlinksModel>();

//Create a list for all the data...
List<getBlinksModel> blinkDetailsListWithGPS = new List<getBlinksModel>();
```

Here is my model...

```
public class getBlinksModel
{
    public string METERNUMBER { get; set; }
    public int BLINKS { get; set; }
    public string SUBNAME { get; set; }
    public string FEEDERNAME { get; set; }
    public string ACCTNUM { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `getBlinksModel` look like

Comment: what do you mean by common **value**?

Comment: Added the model above... and common value, both of the lists have a common column of data for a meternumber and I want the meternumbers on list B that are on list a to show on list a with the longitude and latitude column that shows on list b.

Comment: So both lists might contain METERNUMBER = 5 for example?

Comment: @DavidG that is correct. On ListB that meternumber will have two other columns with it and I want to add those columns to the same meternumber on listA.

Comment: How can the ListB contain extra columns when it is using the same type?

Comment: You seem to need an inner Join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Linq join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), this will join the 2 lists together and return the items where `METERNUMBER` exists in both lists but using the longitude/latitude form `as400GPSList`:

```
List<getBlinksModel> blinkDetailsListWithGPS
            = (from b in blinkList
               join a in as400GPSList
                   on b.METERNUMBER equals a.METERNUMBER
               select new getBlinksModel
               {
                   METERNUMBER = a.METERNUMBER,
                   BLINKS = a.BLINKS,
                   ACCTNUM = a.ACCTNUM,
                   FEEDERNAME = a.FEEDERNAME,
                   SUBNAME = a.SUBNAME,
                   Latitude = b.Latitude,
                   Longitude = b.Longitude
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of .NET you're using, this seems like an appropriate situation for the [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:
`List<getBlinksModel> blinkDetailsListWithGPS = blinkList.Intersect(as400GPSList).ToList();`

---

As others mentioned, it depends what you mean by common value. This method is going create a list `blinkDetailsListWithGPS` made up of elements found in two other lists of the same type `blinkList` and `as400GPSList`.

Comment: That was my original thought however I keet getting cannot implicitly convert type Ienumerable to list. private void getCompleteResult()
        {
            List<getBlinksModel> blinkDetailsListWithGPS = blinkList.Intersect(as400GPSList)

        }

Comment: @CMathis Try converting the IEnumerable to a list with blinkList.Intersect(as400GPSList) .ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get the information you need:

```
var query = from a in blinklist
            join b in as400GPSList on a.METERNUMBER = b.METERNUMBER
            select a;
List<getBlinksModel> joinedList = query.ToList();
```

This specific LINQ expression will return all the items in List A (blinklist) that exist in List B (as400GPSList). If you want to get a new list with BlinkModels A with the values of BlinkModels B, you can use the code that @DavidG posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737291/3633862).

You can change the select statement if you need other information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<getBlinksModel> blinkDetailsListWithGPS = blinkList.Join
(
    as400GPSList,
    x => x.METERNUMBER,
    y => y.METERNUMBER,
    (x, y) => {
        x.Latitude = y.Latitude;
        x.Longitude = y.Longitude;
        return x;
    }
).ToList();
```

Note that this won't create new `getBlinksModel` objects but instead use the objects in `blinkList` and initialize the `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties.